# git-diff: not taking line order into account

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a file in my repository that is generated by a software program.

This program sometimes reorder the lines on that file, which is not really important because line order doesn't matter. The problem is that when performing git-diff it's very difficult to see whether anything has actually changed or not.

Is there anyway to perform a diff in which line order is not taken into account? Or, if not possible with git-diff, any shell command you might think of?

Thanks!

Comment: If line order truly doesn't matter, I suppose you could `sort` the file in some way before you commit it to `git`...

Comment: It doesn't matter but it's more or less ordered to be human-readable. So, I don't want to sort it before commit, but maybe only sort before diff. I don't know if I explain myself.

Comment: Fix the generator so it always produces the file in a fixed canonical order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the end of the day, I'm manually running this command before committing to know whether the file actually changed or it's just a line reorder. Maybe I'll set up a git hook for it.

```
diff -wB <(sort file.txt) <(git show HEAD:file.txt | sort -)
```

This command compares the file in the working directory to the file in the last commit of your branch without taking the line order into account.

In my case, I use `-w` and `-B`, to ignore blank spaces and lines which the program also adds. From `man diff`:

> ```
>    -w, --ignore-all-space
>           ignore all white space
>    -B, --ignore-blank-lines
>           ignore changes whose lines are all blank
> ```

Answer (score 1):

here's a pretty nasty hack using DIFF_EXTERNAL_TOOL:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this will be called with path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode
echo $*
diff -uw <(tr -s '[[:space:]]' < "$2" | sort -fbi) <(tr -s '[[:space:]]' < "$5" | sort -fbi) || true
```

this can be called with, assuming you throw the above script in the `wdiff-sort` program in your `$PATH`:

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=wdiff-sort git diff
```

Here, for example, how I used this to compare a bunch of changes to bind zone files:

```
#!/bin/bash

#                path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode
#echo $*
atomize_zone="sed 's/^@//;/^\;/d;s/[[:space:]][[:space:]]*/ /g' | egrep -v '^.TTL (1D|86400)' | grep -v '; serial' | grep -v 'RR TTL' | grep -v '^.TTL 1H' | egrep -v 'IN SOA (ns1|bureau).koumbit.net' | sort -fbi" 

output=$(diff -uw <(sh -c "$atomize_zone" <"$2") <(sh -c "$atomize_zone" < "$5") || true)

if [ ! -z "$output" ]; then
        echo $1
        cat <<EOF
$output
EOF
```

This must look totally insane, but it actually works great and allows for cleaning up the files in various ways before diffing.

Comment: what's `wdiff-sort` ?

Comment: it's a custom script made of the first few lines in my comment.