# Is there a git diff command that ignores whether the order of lines changed?

Tags: xml, git, salesforce, diff, git-diff

I have a system that is retrieving .xml files from a Salesforce organization. For some of the files, their line number ordering shifts on subsequent retrievals. So if I do the following:

1. Retrieve a file
2. Commit its contents
3. Re-retrieve the file
4. Commit its contents

It's completely possible that the order of the lines in the XML has changed, which causes the diff checker to think that the file has had changes made when that's not the case. Is there any git command or strategy that would help cut down the commit clutter? Perhaps something that simplifies a diff down to a set of the lines, and solely checks whether any of the lines in the set have changes.

Comment: possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771313/git-diff-ignore-reorder

Comment: Diffing tree-structured XML *well* is a difficult problem. [Here's a project on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/xmldiff/).

Comment: Other related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20377294, https://superuser.com/q/184969

Answer (score 0):

You could write a parser that rewrites your xml files in a consistent order, and use it to reformat your files before staging them.

You could then use this parser as a [`clean` filter](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion) (scroll down a bit to view the explanations) to have git automatically apply it on the files you choose.